# How to monitor website status and display like github status?

Tags: performance, github, monitoring, availability

Is there a good way to monitor own website like [GithubStatus](https://status.github.com/) to show APP SERVER AVAILABILITY, MEAN WEB RESPONSE TIME and other benchmarks.

Comment: You may want to check out some of the responses to http://askubuntu.com/questions/9107/what-tools-do-you-use-to-monitor-a-web-server

Comment: Also have a look at https://serverfault.com/, I'm sure they have lots of posts about server and app monitoring.